# is there a way to make widget wait the results of widget that comes before it in flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

Im trying to pass the value of resultMsg  from the FutureBuilder   widget to Text widget ,,but it stills give me the inital value of the variable ,is there a way to build the first widget before ,get the variable change (which is global var) and pass it?
or any other way to do
IM posting my code to show what variable I asked for

```
 child: ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 400,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _getdeptemp(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        int x = (snapshot.data.length);
                        double xx = double.parse(x.toString());
                       //some process
                        resultMsg = ""+Sum ; //*********here is the value I want to assign variable to it************** 
                           
                 return
                        
                         new  charts.LineChart(
                          seriesList(dataa),
                          animate: false,
                          behaviors: [
                            new charts.ChartTitle('Session number',
                                behaviorPosition:
                                    charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                                //titleStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 14),
                                titleOutsideJustification: charts
                                    .OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                            new charts.ChartTitle(
                                'Right Pose Percentage, %',
                                behaviorPosition:
                                    charts.BehaviorPosition.start,
                                //titleStyleSpec: chartsCommon.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 11),
                                titleOutsideJustification: charts
                                    .OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea)
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                    }),
              )),
          Container(
             
              child: new Text(
                resultMsg,//////here is the variable ******
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 16,
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: Make this Container with Text `resultMsg` a part of your FutureBuilder, meaning you will render this Container only when you get the result from FutureBuilder, or it's not the case?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use FutureBuilder's data value at other Widget,
how about you insert that Widget to FutureBuilder inside?

In your case, you need to wrap LineChart and Container widget by Column Widget.

```
I just suggest but I don't know whether the error is because I don't have all source.
<As-is>
-ListView
--FutureBuilder
---LineChart
--Container
---Text

<To-be>
-ListView
--FutureBuilder
---Column
----LineChart
----Container
-----Text

or

-FutureBuilder
--ListView
---LineChart
---Container
----Text
```

And here is suggest code based your code like 'To-be'.

```
ListView(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
              height: 400,
              child: SafeArea(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    future: _getdeptemp(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        int x = (snapshot.data.length);
                        double xx = double.parse(x.toString());
                       //some process
                        resultMsg = ""+Sum ; //*********here is the value I want to assign variable to it************** 
                         return Column(
                           children: [
                            new  charts.LineChart(
                              seriesList(dataa),
                              animate: false,
                              behaviors: [
                                new charts.ChartTitle('Session number',
                                  behaviorPosition:
                                    charts.BehaviorPosition.bottom,
                                  //titleStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 14),
                                  titleOutsideJustification: charts
                                    .OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea),
                                new charts.ChartTitle(
                                  'Right Pose Percentage, %',
                                  behaviorPosition:
                                    charts.BehaviorPosition.start,
                                  //titleStyleSpec: chartsCommon.TextStyleSpec(fontSize: 11),
                                  titleOutsideJustification: charts
                                    .OutsideJustification.middleDrawArea)
                              ],
                            ),
                            Container(
                              child: new Text(
                                resultMsg,//////here is the variable ******
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontSize: 16,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      } else {
                        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                    }),
              )),
          
        ],
      );
```